# Kill sencha app watch process using Node.JS

Tags: process, kill

I'm using Node.JS child_process to spawn a command like so:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    cwd   = __dirname,
    cmd   = '/path/to/sencha app watch',
    child = spawn(
        '/bin/sh',
        ['-c', cmd],
        {
            cwd : cwd,
            env : process.env
        }
    );
```

Which works and I can see the processes:

```
> ps -ef | grep watch
502  9706  9705   0 12:01PM ttys001    0:00.00 /bin/bash /path/to/sencha app watch
502  9718  9706   0 12:01PM ttys001    0:24.80 /usr/bin/java -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -Dapple.awt.UIElement=true -jar /path/to/sencha.jar app watch
```

and child.pid is 9706. If I execute child.kill() sending any signal the command is still running. I need to kill the 9718 process. Is there any way to kill the java process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I went to fix this is to call the /user/bin/java command directly and I can now kill the process correctly. The only issue is have to have path to java.